# When is the category of models of a limit theory a topos?

Tags: ct.category-theory, topos-theory, locally-presentable-categories

If $\mathcal{E}$ is a Grothendieck topos on a small base, then it is locally presentable, and hence is equivalent to the category of models of some limit theory.

Is there a characterization of limit theories $\mathcal{T}$ such that the category of models of $\mathcal{T}$ is a topos?  The category of models of a $\mathcal{T}$ is locally presentable and hence a reflective subcategory of presheaves on $\mathcal{T}$.  If there is a characterization of these theories, is it automatic that the reflector is finitely continuous, and hence gives the theories that underly Grothendieck toposes?

I know that Johnstone characterizes the product theories whose models are toposes.  Here $\mathcal{T}$ must have no pseudoconstants and be sufficiently unary.  I guess I'm curious if anyone has generalized this result.

Comment: I don't know this result of Johnstone you are refering to, could you provide a more precise reference ? that sound interesting.

Comment: @SimonHenry I imagine Jonathan is referring to Johnstone's paper "When is a variety a topos?", Algebra Universalis 21 (1985), 198-212. An interesting point made in that paper is that alongside the obvious family of examples of finite product theories whose models form a topos (namely, M-sets for a monoid M), there's a not-so-obvious family: the so-called Jónsson-Tarski algebras and generalizations thereof. A JT algebra is a set $A$ equipped with a bijection $A \to A \times A$.

Comment: @TomLeinster.  Yes, that is correct the reference I was referring to.  A link I have is https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01188056.pdf but I don't know if it's available without subscription.

Comment: Thanks ! I knew about the example of Jonsson-Tarski algebras but I wasn't aware of such a characterization.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My collaborator *Julia Ramos González* and I are working on this question precisely in these days.

A part of the answer is already cointained in a paper by *Carboni, Pedicchio and Rosický*: **[Syntactic characterizations of various classes of locally presentable categories](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0022-4049(01)00016-0)**, Journal of Pure and Applied Algebra, 161 (2001) pp 65-90.

Putting together **Thm. 5** and **19** one gets that:

> A finitely presentable category is a Grothendieck topos if and only if the full subcategory of finitely presentable objects is extensive and pro-exact.

Please, read also the **paragraph that comments Thm. 19**.

Recall that the full subcategory of finitely presentable objects is essentially the limit theory that presents the locally (finitely) presentable category, i.e. $$\mathcal{K} \cong \text{Lex}(\text{Pres}(\mathcal{K})^{\circ}, \text{Set}). $$

---

3 March 2019.

As I was mentioning in the previous version of this answer, together with *Julia*, we worked on a generalization of this statement to the infinitary case and related the site-theoretic presentation with the limit-theory presentation. The result of this investigation, **Gabriel-Ulmer duality for topoi and its relation with site presentations**, is now on the arXiv:[1902.09391](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.09391).